# Android Emulator black screen on Phenom II X4 965

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I can not start the android emulator on my machine. I can see the phone "frame" but the content is black.

I also tried to start the emulator from command line and I get the following error messages:

```
./emulator -avd Pixel_3_Edited_API_28
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.5.0 (build_id 7285888) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
cannot add library /home/ps/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
added library /home/ps/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
cannot add library /home/ps/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.1 [bit 19]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]
qemu-system-x86_64: can't open backing store /home/ps/.android/avd/Pixel_3_Edited_API_28.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img for guest RAM: Permission denied
qemu-system-x86_64: falling back to regular RAM allocation.
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
```

Is my computer to old? Do I need a newer CPU?

System
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965
Linux Mint 19.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your computer is too old, see

emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3

even you are lucky enough to be able to start it, it would not be in usable performance. You should either buy a new computer or use a cloud service to do it. Any recent i5 desktop with like 8gb ram should have given you usable performance.